# Beanstalkd - is it possible to pause a tube and keep processing other tubes?

Tags: beanstalkd

I am not that familiar with Beanstalkd.

My list of jobs ready is just increasing over time and I need to discover which tube is processing broken jobs. Is there a way to pause a Beanstalkd tube to try to process the jobs on that queue and let other tubes take priority to be processed?

I am trying to avoid to lose all the jobs on the queue and discover a way to let other jobs to be processed while we fix and find the broken tube.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to read a job from the tube, you first have to `watch` the tube. You can also `ignore` a previously watched tube.

> Consumers can show interest in tubes by sending the "watch" command;
>   they can show disinterest by sending the "ignore" command. This set of
>   interesting tubes is said to be a consumer's "watch list". When a
>   client reserves a job, it may come from any of the tubes in its watch
>   list.

Comment: I ended up watching the tube and all looked fined. By the end I discover that a minor php update has broken the system. Thanks for the help!